# how to apply regex find in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
 "category" : {
   "100" : {
      "location" : "class.xyz.20"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I direct Apply regex on location key field in MongoDB Like

{"location" : {'$regex' : "class."}}

how can I Do That

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used regex in aggregate pipelines, You can try it out on find too (not sure on the syntax for `find` you can check the docs for it).

Here is how I used regEx in Aggregate.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { "field": { $regex: "someText", $options: 'i'} } }
]);
```

You can read more about options [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/#regexmatch-options)